# What counts towards the score?

Tags: discussion, score, tag-score

I am a bit confused by how the score system works, and I did not find any post online to address my question.

If for example, I have an answer with one upvote - does that count towards the score of all the tags mentioned in the question? or only accepted answers count toward the score of these tags? and if so, how much does an accepted answer with 0 upvotes (or the same amount of upvotes + downvotes) count?

I am talking of this kind of score:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for) - See the link [Tag Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/341145) and then navigate to the section under the heading **What is a tag score?**

Comment: @SamOnela I literally saw that post and it was a dig so I CBA to read it, but now I finally had the power to do it, however one more question if you may - do accepted answers count more than one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms), the score means:

> When referring to a post (question or answer) it means the total
> amount of upvotes, minus total number of downvotes. For example answer
> with 8 upvotes and 3 downvotes has score of 5. (The number displayed
> to the right of each post is the net score)

The score is in no way related to Accepted answers.

If your answer has 1 upvote and no downvotes, then its score is 1.  This contributes a score of one to each of the tags on the question.

If your answer is accepted, but it has a score of 0, then the answer does not contribute any score to the tags on the question.